# Unable to play h264 stream in Android VideoView

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, h.264, android-videoview

I'm writing an application that should play h.264 stream from an *Axis M7014 Video Encoder* through a `VideoView` component.
My original intent was to play a `mjpg` content over an `rtsp` transport protocol but I'm open to any other solution (compatibile with this video encoder).
Speaking with *Axis* support I found that the only possibile arrangement of format / protocol playable trough **Android** native components should be `h.264` over `rtsp`.

This's the code of the `Activity` responsible of playing the video.
I put also an `EditText` to insert the stream URI and a `Button` to start video:

```
package it.acme.tux.controllerview;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean playing = false;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private EditText textUri;
    private Button buttonPlay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        textUri = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.video_uri);
        videoView=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        buttonPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_play);

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                videoView.start();
                playing = true;
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                playing = false;
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void playVideo(View view)
    {
        if(!playing) {
            String uri = (String) textUri.getText();
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
        }
        else {
            videoView.stopPlayback();
            playing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

this's the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="it.acme.tux.controllerview.CameraActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/video_uri"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/default_uri"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="playVideo"
            android:text="@string/action_play_title"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The strings used in layout:

```
<resources>
    <string name="action_play_title">Play</string>
    <string name="default_uri">http://192.168.10.101:8080/stream</string>
</resources>
```

As far as I can see `OnPreparedListener` it's never triggered as also `OnCompletionListener` or `OnErrorListener`. I read everything I found over there and I also read `MediaPlayer` class docs without luck (the only good suggestion I took is to start the video playback once `OnPreparedListener` event is fired).

BTW When unavailable I simulate *video encoder* stream trough *VLC* in this way:

```
vlc.exe video.mp4 --repeat :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,scale=Auto,acodec=none}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/stream} :sout-all :sout-keep
```

I'm pretty sure this stream works because I'm able to view the `h.264` streaming from VLC from the same **Android** phone I use to test my application (of course with an external viewer).

Where I'm wrong? Why the `OnPreparedListener` event is never fired?

I tried also a different approach using a `SurfaceView` component instead `VideoView` and `MediaPlayer` `SurfaceHolder` instances but I had not luck either.
This's the code:

```
package it.acme.tux.test;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener
{
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceView videoView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean play = false;
    private EditText textUri;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        textUri = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textUri);

        surfaceHolder = videoView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    void playAction(View view){
        try {
            String source = textUri.getText().toString();
            Log.d("MainActivity"  , "Playing: " + source);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(source);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.d("MainActivity"  , "Completed");
        play = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
        Log.d("MainActivity"  , String.format("Info %d/%d", i, i1));
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
        Log.d("MainActivity"  , String.format("Info %d/%d", i, i1));
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.d("MainActivity"  , "Prepared");
        mediaPlayer.start();
        play = true;
    }
}
```

The only data I had from this is a more detailed progress of what's happening from the `prepareAsync` to the `start` of the video (that ultimately didn't lead to errors but neither shows up any video). In this case the `OnPreparedListener` event seems to be fired:

```
12-18 15:44:51.320 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture
12-18 15:44:51.320 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync
12-18 15:44:51.323 14445-14522/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=200, ext1=701, ext2=0
12-18 15:44:51.323 14445-14522/it.acme.tux.test W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (701, 0)
12-18 15:44:51.323 14445-14522/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: callback application
12-18 15:44:51.323 14445-14522/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
12-18 15:44:51.330 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test D/MainActivity: Info: 701 / 0
12-18 15:44:51.333 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 0 (msec)
12-18 15:44:51.636 14445-14457/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=200, ext1=10972, ext2=0
12-18 15:44:51.636 14445-14457/it.acme.tux.test W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (10972, 0)
12-18 15:44:51.636 14445-14457/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: callback application
12-18 15:44:51.636 14445-14457/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
12-18 15:44:51.637 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test D/MainActivity: Info: 10972 / 0
12-18 15:44:51.638 14445-14522/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
12-18 15:44:51.638 14445-14522/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: New video size 0 x 0
12-18 15:44:51.638 14445-14522/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: callback application
12-18 15:44:51.639 14445-14522/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
12-18 15:44:58.645 14445-14458/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=200, ext1=702, ext2=0
12-18 15:44:58.645 14445-14458/it.acme.tux.test W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
12-18 15:44:58.645 14445-14458/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: callback application
12-18 15:44:58.646 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test D/MainActivity: Info: 702 / 0
12-18 15:44:58.647 14445-14458/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
12-18 15:44:58.647 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 0 (msec)
12-18 15:44:59.645 14445-14458/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
12-18 15:44:59.645 14445-14458/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: prepared
12-18 15:44:59.645 14445-14458/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: callback application
12-18 15:44:59.646 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
12-18 15:44:59.647 14445-14458/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
12-18 15:44:59.652 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: invoke 68
12-18 15:44:59.659 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test D/MainActivity: Prepared
12-18 15:44:59.659 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer-JNI: start
12-18 15:44:59.659 14445-14445/it.acme.tux.test V/MediaPlayer: start
```

I tried also to use this uri:

```
rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov
```

that's of course an `h.264` stream over `rtsp`.

To summarize my request I need an help to fix this. Why the video is not being played?

There are third party components to play h.264 streams (**Android Dev Studio 3.0.1** compatible)?
How can I play a *MJPEG* stream?

Best regards,
 Mike

Comment: Any kind of info/warning?

Comment: @Myszsoda nope. But maybe I'm failing to test it. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you do call playVideo (where that View is pointless), so mediaPlayer should return something in Logcat.

Comment: more recently I tried also to use `SurfaceView` (instead `VideoView`) component with a `MediaPlayer` instance without luck (again).

Comment: @Myszsoda `playVIdeo` is started by `onClick` event of `action_play` button I don't know if an event handler can be declared without the `View` argument. Anyway in future I may need this argument to discriminate which widget triggered the event (with the assumption I will add more buttons etc)

Comment: So I was looking through the docs of `Axis M7014 Video Encoder` which seems to support RTP/RTSP which Android supports. If the Axis Encoder is transmitting the stream, does an existing Android app (VLC, etc.) play the stream - this wasn't clear from your OP. If not could it be (a) security on the server (I saw mention of login) and/or (b) h.264 isn't configured for Android, I do see a config page in Axis for h.264. For Android h.264 req see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html and https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.0/android-8.0-cdd#5_2_video_encoding

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes I can play the stream coming from this Video Encoder trough *VLC* (also on Android).

Answer (score 5):

I have used rtsp with wowza.Few ways i'll let you know

try it once and let me know if you got issue.If your streaming in vlc working fine then something problem with app side. If these methods are not working then try with different phone. It also help you.

**1. Try with videoview**

```
vvVideoPlay = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvVideoPlay);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

String videoUrl = "rtsp://184.72.239.149:8554/vid.mp4";

    mediaController.setAnchorView(vvVideoPlay);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
    vvVideoPlay.setVideoURI(uri);
    vvVideoPlay.setMediaController(mediaController);
    vvVideoPlay.requestFocus();

    vvVideoPlay.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mp.start();
            pdialog.dismiss();
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**2. Try with direct your phone player**

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("rtsp://184.72.239.149:8554/vid.mp4")));
```

**3. Third way try to with this library with custom player in your app.**

**Step1.** Add it to your gradle

```
compile "fm.jiecao:jiecaovideoplayer:4.7.0"
```

**Step2.** Add it as your video play in xml layout.

```
<fm.jiecao.jcvideoplayer_lib.JCVideoPlayerStandard
    android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Step 3.** Check from here how to use this library in your class,

```
public class PlayVideoActivity extends BaseActivity {

@BindView(R.id.videoPlayer)
JCVideoPlayerStandard mVideoPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    restoreFromIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public int getLayout() {
    return R.layout.activity_play_video;
}


// get video path from intent and play the video here
private void restoreFromIntent(Intent intent) {

    mVideoPlayer.setUp("rtsp://184.72.239.149:8554/vid.mp4"
            , JCVideoPlayerStandard.SCREEN_LAYOUT_LIST, "");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (JCVideoPlayer.backPress()) {
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    JCVideoPlayer.releaseAllVideos();
}
}
```

Hope this will help you to fix your problem.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ExoPlayer supports the H.264 AVC Codec streams. Here is the solution.
First you have to specify the dependency for the ExoPlayer in **Build.Gradle(Module app) file**, Keep in mind that i am using the **2.8.0** version of ExoPlayer.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.8.0'
```

In XML file, make the **PlayerView** container of the ExoPlayer in which you will play the video.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/playerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"> 
    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PlayerView playerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        playerView=findViewById(R.id.playerView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        simpleExoPlayer= ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,new DefaultTrackSelector());
        DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory=new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this,"YourApplicationName"));
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        ExtractorMediaSource extractorMediaSource=new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.video));
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(extractorMediaSource);
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        playerView.setPlayer(null);
        simpleExoPlayer.release();
        simpleExoPlayer=null;
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use exoplayer. it supports more formats of video.
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: Library works everywhere, question is if it supports your Android device

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S8

Comment: tried **ExoPlayer**... works pretty good with `h.264` over `http`, but it has no support for `mjpg` and for `rtsp` protocol.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

  Seems android does not support that extension

Comment: yep it does not I was hoping exoPlayer had an extension for this format / protocol.

Comment: @AnuradhaSawant exoPlayer is pratically useless in my specific case... I've not been able to find a way to access `h.264` streams produced within my *Axis encoder* since the only trasport protocol available for `h.264` seems to be `rtsp` or `rtsp` over `http` tunneling.